# Why does python packaging documentation say __init__.py file of package should be empty?

Tags: python

Based on the the documentation for [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#:%7E:text=__init__.py%20is%20required%20to%20import%20the%20directory%20as%20a%20package%2C%20and%20should%20be%20empty.), `__init__.py` should be empty. I want to know why? because I'm placing certain objects in the `__init__.py` file that are used in every module in the Package. On checking bunch of `__init.py__` files in my local environments for standard packages like importlib, multiprocessing etc. All of them have a bunch of code in the file.

Comment: It should be empty *for that simple example project*. This does not apply to other projects, just like the part about `def add_one(number): return number + 1` doesn't apply to all projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking that statement as more general than it's meant. You're reading a statement from a tutorial, where they walk you through creating a simple example project. *That particular example project's* `__init__.py` should be empty, simply because the example doesn't need to do anything in `__init__.py`.

Most projects' `__init__.py` files will not be empty. Taking a few examples from popular packages, such as [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/__init__.py), [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py), [flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/src/flask/__init__.py), [sortedcontainers](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers/blob/master/sortedcontainers/__init__.py), or the stdlib [asyncio](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py), none of these example `__init__.py` files are empty. They may perform package initialization, import things from submodules into the main package namespace, or include metadata like `__all__`, `__version__`, or a package docstring. The example project is just simplified to the point where it doesn't have any of that.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I believe its not clear enough in the tutorial text and can cause confusion.

Answer (score 7):

The sole purpose of `__init__.py` is to indicate that the folder containing this file is a package, and to treat this folder as package, that's why it is recommended to leave it empty.

Consider following hierarchy:

```
foo
    __init__.py
    bar.py
```

When you use `from foo import bar` or `import foo.bar`, Python interpreter will look for `__init__.py` in `foo` folder, if it finds it, the `bar` module will be imported else it won't; however, this behavior has changed over the time, and it may be able to successfully import the modules/packages even if `__init__.py` is missing, but remember Zen of Python: *Explicit is better than implicit*, so it's always safe to have it.

But in case, if you need some package level variables to be defined, you can do it inside the `__init__.py` file, and all the modules inside the package will be able to use it.

And in fact, if you look at [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id15), it mentions that the `__init__.py` can also contain the documentation for package level information.

Comment: Exactly, If we think about Zen here, telling the reader `init should be empty` for me meant it should always be empty.  I think it could be written in a better way. As you can see there are conflicting answers within this thread.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there are three things you need to be aware of when you create a non-empty `__init__` file:

- it might be more difficult to follow the code. If you instantiate `a = B()` in `__init__` it's even worse. I know developers who don't like it only for this reason
- on package import contents of `__init__` are evaluated. Sometimes it might be computation heavy or simply not needed.
- namespace conflicts. You can't really instantiate `bar` in init and have a `bar.py` file in your package.

I like importing package contents in `__init__` as otherwise in bigger projects import statements become ugly. Overall it's not a good or bad practice. This advice applies only to the project in this particular example.

Answer (score -1):

In some case, you didn't have any shared component in your package. Suppose Defining a little package for calculating some algorithms, Then you didn't need any shared component in your `__init__`